# Autodesk Forge Viewer Measuring Tool on glTF models

Tags: autodesk-forge, measure, gltf

We have been using Autodesk Forge for viewing our STL 3D models, this has been working great.

We have some new file types, glTF (.glb) that we would like to use.  Unfortunately the Measuring Tool in the Viewer is only allowing a small area for measurement.

When the model is loading into the viewer it is loading it in "sections".  I am only able to measure one of those sections.

You can view an example here:
https://architecturalinfo.com/autodesk-forge/viewer-test.html

I appreciate your help.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

From your demo site, I can see you're using a legacy Forge Viewer (v6.6.4), please consider upgrading it to v7 at least. Our engineering team made lots of improvements on this.

I tested the sample [experiment/gltf2](https://github.com/petrbroz/forge-basic-app/tree/experiment/gltf2) from this blog, and it looks fine. The measurement tool works as expected.

https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/gltf-20-support-forge-viewer

[image]